# I wanna use selenium and python to get information which use 'post' method

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I wanna use selenium and python to get information named '投资金额' and '投资数量' within the black frame  in example1 which request method is 'post'. My code are as follows, that is on again off again. Need your help!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.pedata.cn/invest_count/list.html")
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
invest = soup.find('div', 'tj_chart').find('div')
print(invest.string)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this website, the data are not embedded in the html page, it's loaded via Javascript from another API (POST https://www.pedata.cn/ajax/invest_count/list). The easiest way to get all the data in your chart is to call that API directly rather than waiting for the JS to load the data :

```
import requests

response = requests.post(
    'https://www.pedata.cn/ajax/invest_count/list',
    data = {
        'investStart': '',
        'investEnd': '',
        'x': 1,
        'currency': '',
        'month': '',
        'round': '',
        'investStage': '',
        'investType': '',
        'investTime': '',
        'xType': '',
        'city': '',
        'industry': ''
    }
)

print(response.json()['data'])
```